# Why is QWidget's destructor not virtual?

Tags: c++, qt, virtual, qwidget

Looking at qwidget.h, I found the destructor as below:

```
~QWidget();
```

I was wondering why this is not declared as virtual

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The destructor is virtual, because QWidget derives from QObject which does have a virtual destructor. Why it's not declared virtual in the code is a either style issue or a harmless mistake. I would have declared it virtual myself.

Comment: Actually, in C++ a method in a subclass is virtual if it is declared as such in the base class, so in this case the virtual keyword is not necessary for QWidget. Like John, I would also have added the virtual keyword for subclasses.

Comment: @john, I was under a false impression that `virtual` does not trickle down the inheritance chain implicitly. Turns out I was wrong. Thanks for pointing that out!